# SQL Out of range value in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have problem with Out of range value in SQL, when i run it in C# Debug. But Select with Conversion of datetime, works directly in SQL. what can i do..?

```
WHERE (Edu_Table_1.chatardeba = CONVERT(DATETIME, '" + datesList[dd] + "', 103)) 

...

List<DateTime> datesList = new List<DateTime>();
DataTable dt1 = DataObjects.FetchFromDatabase(String.Format("SELECT date from dates_table", magalkurseli, examType), this.serverAddress, this.dbCatalog); 
if (dt1 != null && dt1.Rows.Count > 0) 
{ 
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt1.Rows) 
    {
        datesList.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(dr["tarigi"])); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: what datetime value are you trying to convert?

Comment: Is there any chance that you can show us something?

Comment: You can post code, for example...

Comment: You haven't given us nearly enough information to help you. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: Please edit new information into the post rather than posting it in the comments.

Comment: What's the data type of the `date` column in the table `dates_table`? Is it `datetime`, `datetime2`, `date`, `time` , `datetimeoffset`, `smalldatetime` ... or something else? Is it nullable? Since SQL Server datetime data types fall within the domain of `System.DateTime` (1 Jan 0001 CE 00:00:00.000 through 31 Dec 9999 CE 23:59:59.9999999) it shouldn't be a problem. Your use of  `Convert.ToDateTime()` suggests that your are handing back something other than a SQL Server date/time data type: what that is would help narrow down the problem.

Comment: @Nicholas Carey its datetime. but what can i use instead Convert.ToDateTime()?

Comment: @Dimitry: nothing. The .Net runtime automagickally converts it to `System.DateTime` (or `DBNull` if it is a SQL Server `null` value) and returns it as an `object`. ALl you have to do is cast it. Something like `DateTime? value = null ; if (dr[0] is DateTime) value = (DateTime)dr[0] ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is easy problem to fix, and this happen because your database format is different form .Net datetime fromat ( you may send day as month )
 all you have to do is:

- open sql management studio and run "select GETDATE()"  it will return you the database datetime format,
- when you receive or send date to the database make sure to change it format to the same database format.

  // example , datetime in database is 
    13-03-2013
  // change format of .Net Date object 
  dt.toString("dd-MM-yyyy");

Answer (score 2):

There's not a lot of information to go on here, but based on problems I've seen other developers run into, I can make a guess on whats going on...

The default value of a `DateTime` object in .NET is not within the valid range of a `datetime` data type in sql. This usually happens when you have a non-nullable `DateTime` property or parameter that you don't initialize to a valid value (or set to `default(DateTime)`).

The solution, generally is to use a nullable column and `DateTime?` in any related c# objects **or** always initialize your `DateTime` properties to a value within the range that sql expects.